# python: from __future__ import print_function must be in every loaded module?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm not a professional programmer, so I have some big holes in my knowledge (just a heads up).

I have written a few libraries in python 3.7. But now I want to access them from a 3D app which uses python 2.7. The only real 3.7 specific features that they have (as far as I can tell at the moment) are configparser (vs. ConfigParser) and the print function.

I am handling the configparser issue by catching an importerror and then loading the 2.7 version instead.

I am trying to handle the print function by adding this line to the top of my script that is running in the 3D application:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

But when I import a module that has a python 3 style print function in it I get a syntax error. If, however, I include the `from __future__` statement in the loaded module, everything works.  Clearly I am running into the limits of my knowledge here.

Here is the entire code for the module I am importing (called test.py):

```
import sys

def print_error():
    print("AND THIS IS?", file=sys.stderr)
```

And here is the code inside the 3D app (running python 2.7) that calls this code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/Documents/dev/")
print("WHY IS THIS NOT A SYNTAX ERROR?", file=sys.stderr)
from mylib import test
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
WHY IS THIS NOT A SYNTAX ERROR?
00:00:08    Traceback (most recent call last):
00:00:08      File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
00:00:08      File "/home/me/Documents/dev/mylib/test.py", line 4
00:00:08        print("AND THIS IS?", file=sys.stderr)
00:00:08                                  ^
00:00:08    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
00:00:08
```

But if I put the `from __future__` line in the test.py module, everything runs correctly.

Am I doing something wrong? Or do I need to have this line in each module. And if so, how do I reconcile that with the times I will be calling these libraries from python 3.7 (where I do not want to load the print function `from __future__`)?

From my research it appears that the `from __future__` is a compiler directive which controls how the script is compiled at run time? Maybe?  I'm in over my head on this bit.  But does that mean each time a module is loaded that the compiler has to be reminded to use `from __future__`?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3, `print` is [a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), and in Python 2 it is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#print), so basically in Python 2, it is not expecting the parameter `file`.

You will have to add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of each module, to disable the statement and use the `print()` function, use this future statement at the top of your module.

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html#module-__future__), `__future__` serves 3 purposes:

1. Avoid confusing existing tools that analyze import statements and to find the modules they’re importing.
2. Ensure future statements run under releases prior to 2.1 at least yield runtime exceptions.
3. Document when incompatible changes were introduced, and when they will be — or were — made mandatory.

Comment: And because `print` is a statement, not a function, the comma defines a tuple, not an argument list, and a tuple literal cannot contain a key-value pair like `file=sys.stderr`. Python 2 interprets the statement the same way it would `t=("...", file=sys.stderr); print t`.

Comment: @chepner, exactly!

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it clearly explains what it is that I need to do (include the statement at the top of each module). But I'm still not sure why including it once at the top of the first module being run isn't sufficient. Clearly it has something to do with how the python interpreter works when it loads modules. Regardless, I now know what I need to do. Thank you so much.